# jQuery isotope invalid rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, jquery-isotope

Why are these two fiddles different? I mean shouldn't they stick to each other in the first fiddle too as in the second fiddle?

Fiddle1: http://jsfiddle.net/gopi1410/EABJw/

Fiddle2: http://jsfiddle.net/gopi1410/EABJw/1/

The only difference in the fiddles is that the first one has the css: `#id2 {width: 240px;}` while the second fiddle has `#id2 {width: 140px;}`

**Is it a bug in the isotope plugin or am I missing some basic point?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your javascript like this:

```
$(function() {
    var $container = $('#container');
    $container.isotope({
        masonry: {columnWidth: 1},
        itemSelector: '.item'          
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah, thanks!! I thought the default for coulumnWidth was 1, just read the documentation to find it took the width of first div as default..